# Would the charges in a current-carrying wire move to the centre of the wire due to attractive magnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, charge

We know that the magnetic force acting on two parallel wires carrying current in the same direction is attractive.

I am wondering: Say we have a thick wire carrying current, with initially the same charge density throughout the wire. If we view the thick wire as a bundle of many thinner wires, then these thinner wires would experience attractive magnetic force towards each other.

Following this logic, would the charges inside a thick current-carrying wire move towards the centre of the wire due to attractive magnetic force?